# Databind to property that should only be modified by functions

Tags: c#, data-binding, maui

I have a observable collection of data that must not be modified outside the use of functions. Therefore it has to be a private property. However I need to expose it to the view so that I can bind the information inside it. What is the best way of doing this?

My first though would be to copy the data inside, but then I need to do shallow copies and it would just be a whole lot of wasted work if there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: Make it public and readonly

Comment: Or make it public with a private setter, so that only methods inside the class can modify it

Comment: First explain to me how you managed to get the View to modify the ObservableCollection. Then we will talk about how to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using a [ReadOnlyObservableCollection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlyobservablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) to wrap your ObservableCollection. In sum,

> This class is a read-only wrapper around an ObservableCollection. If changes are made to the underlying collection, the ReadOnlyObservableCollection reflects those changes.

Suppose we want to bind to a ObservableCollection named **ItemsCollection** in viewmodel.

```
public class MainPageViewModel 
{

    private readonly ObservableCollection<string> ItemsCollection;
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> ItemsCollectionReadOnly { get; }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {

        ItemsCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        ItemsCollectionReadOnly = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>(ItemsCollection);

    }


    //in this class, we could modify the ItemsCollection, and the ReadOnlyObservableCollection also reflect the changes.
    public Command ClickedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() =>
            {

                ItemsCollection.Add("11111");

            });              
        }
    }

}
```

And in xaml, we just expose **ItemsCollectionReadOnly** property. And in other class we cannot modify the **ItemsCollection**:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ClickedCommand}" Text="Click me1" />
<CollectionView x:Name="mycol" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollectionReadOnly}">
.....
</CollectionView>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal of allowing data binding without exposing the original collection directly, you can consider using a combination of techniques:

1. **Read-Only Property:** Make your observable collection a private field within your class and expose it as a read-only property. This way, external code cannot modify the collection directly.

```cs
   private ObservableCollection<YourDataType> _dataCollection = new ObservableCollection<YourDataType>();

   public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<YourDataType> DataCollection
   {
       get { return new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<YourDataType>(_dataCollection); }
   }
```

2. **ViewModel Pattern:** If you're dealing with data binding in a UI context, you might consider using the MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) pattern. In this pattern, your observable collection resides in a ViewModel, and the ViewModel exposes properties that the View can bind to. This keeps your data encapsulated and controlled while allowing the View to access the required data.

```cs
   public class YourViewModel
   {
       private ObservableCollection<YourDataType> _dataCollection = new ObservableCollection<YourDataType>();

       public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<YourDataType> DataCollection
       {
           get { return new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<YourDataType>(_dataCollection); }
       }

       // Other properties and methods for data manipulation
   }
```

In XAML, you can then bind to the ViewModel's properties.

Remember, there is often a trade-off between encapsulation and performance. If your collection is large and the copying becomes a performance concern, you might need to carefully assess the design and decide whether a more permissive approach is warranted. However, in most cases, encapsulating the data and exposing only what's necessary is a good practice for maintaining a clean and manageable codebase.